# Quarkus AWS Lambda invalid Entrypoint Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, quarkus-native

I have simple kotlin, quarkus project which is build to native with command:
`./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` 
When my friend who is using macbook m1 uploades `function.zip` generated by quarkus like that:[AWS function.zip upload UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Wzl.png)
it works fine, but when i do the same from my PC which is ubuntu 22.04 i get:
`invalid Entrypoint  Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint`.
Please help :(
As said before i did `./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` and then uploaded from .zip with `function.zip` but when i invoke lambda it sais `invalid Entrypoint  Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint`

Comment: in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/deploy-quarkus-based-applications-using-aws-lambda-with-aws-sam/) says use ```sam init -a x86_64 -r java11 -p Zip -d maven -n java11-mvn-default``` for creating the function. error you are getting sounds like you are trying to run arm64 on x86 or vice versa.

Comment: Indeed. You were right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/deploy-quarkus-based-applications-using-aws-lambda-with-aws-sam/) says use `sam init -a x86_64 -r java11 -p Zip -d maven -n java11-mvn-default` for creating the function. The error you are getting sounds like you are trying to run **arm64** on **x86** or vice versa.